# GNOME Shell Extensions. Ubuntu Dock is missing extension.js

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dock, extension

Ubuntu Dock in GNOME Shell Extensions is missing extension.js

[image]

Comment: any update about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to this [Gnome extension applications menu](https://extensions.gnome.org//extension/6/applications-menu/)
2. install gnome extension in your browser
3. You will see an icon on the right with an error just double-click on it will fix the error.
4. you should see instead of error this icon

Hope that helps
[image]

**update**
for more info check this
[How to install Gnome Shell Extensions on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish Linux Desktop](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux-desktop)